# Rails: Issue with less after bootstrap update -- Cannot load such file -- less

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-rails

It all was working fine before bootstrap update but now i have this error:

```
cannot load such file -- less
 (in /home/warch/development/railcast_196/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)`
```

i tried to google this with no luck, i already added the less gems specified in the latest bug resolve:

`Gemfile` extract:

```
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'
...
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233465/less-js-loaderror-no-such-file-to-load-less-on-main-less-file ?

Comment: Thank you @MrYoshiji i gladly found a duplicate of my problem.

Comment: Okay great, you should post an answer yourself and accept it as valid answer for next users ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding twitter-boostrap-rails with an existing rails app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232945/adding-twitter-boostrap-rails-with-an-existing-rails-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was gladly a resolved duplicate of:

[Adding twitter-bootstrap-rails with an existing rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232945/adding-twitter-boostrap-rails-with-an-existing-rails-app)

I only need to restart as @[danieleds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472470/danieleds) answered.

Answer (score 3):

add in your Gemfile in assets group

gem 'less', '2.2.2'  # (at this date)